# C++ return a list of values?

Tags: c++, list, templates

I have a list with 20 numbers in it (theList). I want to read it backards and have this function to do that:

```
template<typename T>
T funktioner<T>::swap(list<T> &theList)
{
list<T> li;
auto start = theList.rbegin(), stop = theList.rend();
for (auto it = start; it != stop; ++it)
{
    li.push_back(*it);
}

return li;
}
```

I call the function from my UserInterface in this function:

```
template<typename T>
void UserInterface<T>::swap()
{
cout << func.swap(List) << endl;

}
```

But this doesn't work correctly and I get the following error message:

```
error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::list<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>'to 'int'
error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::list<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>'to 'double'
```

Why? I don't know what I'm doing wrong this time. I thought that I had to create a temporary list and push_back the values in to that and return that list, but I guess I was wrong and I'm really not good at this. Can someone help me? Maybe I'm totally out of bed here? :O

Comment: The return type is `T`, not `list<T>`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I still dont know what to do, but I guess I have to figure that out by myself, because I can see that my question is getting a lot of negative response, so I guess Im just stupid. :(

Comment: If you want to return a list of T, then do *that* rather than returning a T. Also, ints are not doubles.

Comment: @LogicStuff sure, was just stating the obvious. The T vs list of T bit is what really matters.

Comment: @StudentLerning Is there something hard to understand about the error messages? Your intentions were good, but that does not mean you can't make a typo and not try to read them.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but still; why `list`? In almost *any* situation a `vector` would be preferential (perform better in practice)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you declare to return type `T`, but the variable you return has type `list<T>`. I'd suggest to develop your code with concrete types (and without templates) first; you can exchange the concrete type with placeholders afterwards, but concrete types give a better idea what actually happens. 
Try the following code and translate it then to a template:

```
list<int> swapList(list<int> &theList)
{
    list<int> li;
    auto start = theList.rbegin(), stop = theList.rend();
    for (auto it = start; it != stop; ++it)
    {
        li.push_back(*it);
    }

    return li;
}

int main()
{
    list<int> source { 1,2,3,4 };
    list<int> swapped = swapList(source);
    for (auto i : swapped) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```